# xmodmap: `Shift+CapsLock` -> `Delete` returns error bell

Tags: linux, xmodmap, capslock, setxkbmap

Because `CapsLock` has the keycode `66` on my `English_US` keyboard layout, the command

```
xmodmap -e "clear Lock" -e "keycode 66 shift = Delete BackSpace"
```

turns `CapsLock` into the `Delete` key and `Shift+CapsLock` into `BackSpace`.

If I want to swap the mappings of `CapsLock` and `Shift+CapsLock` by

```
xmodmap -e "clear Lock" -e "keycode 66 shift = BackSpace Delete"
```

then `Shift+CapsLock` does not delete the character under the cursor but gives an error bell. Albeit `xev` shows that the correct keysymbol `Delete` is passed to X. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
 key <CAPS> { [ NoSymbol, Delete ] };
```

is in ~/.Xkbmap, then `<Shift-CAPS>` sends `<SHIFT-DELE>`.

Instead, if

```
 key <CAPS> { actions = [ NoAction(), Redirect(key=<DELE>,clearmods=all) ] };
```

then `<Shift-CAPS>` sends `<DELE>`.

The necessity of the `Redirect(...)` action in this case rests a mystery to me.